# How to fix this ESlint (no-param-reassign) error in my Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to find only users that have a specific service. Each user has an array of Services. And the match I need to find is the following:

`userService.name === service.name && !user.disabled`

Code below works, but has ESlint errors dealing with a param-reassignment.

[image]

---

```
export const matchUserWithService = (user, userService, service) => {
  if (userService.name === service.name && !user.disabled) {
    user.isMatched = true;
    userService.rights = service.rights;
  }

  return userService;
};

export const renderServiceAdmins = (users, selectedService) => {
  const usersWithService = users.filter((user) => {
    user.services.map(usrSrv => matchUserWithService(user, usrSrv, selectedService));
    if (user.isMatched) return user;
    return false;
  });

  return usersWithService.map(user => user.services.map(service => service.rights.map((right) => {
    if (
      service.name === selectedService.name &&
      lowCase(right.name) === 'admin' &&
      !right.disabled
    ) {
      return (
        <li key={user.email + randId()}>
          { user.name } | <span className="info_blue">{ user.email }</span>
        </li>
      );
    }
    return null;
  })));
};
```

Could this be refactored with `.find`?

Comment: [You're not doing anything really weird](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). Why not just turn the rule off in your `.eslintrc` file?

Comment: @Andy because we're required to super ahead to eslint :(

Comment: I get that. I'm not talking about getting rid of ESLint, but just turning off the rule for`no-param-reassign`. For example, if I ever had that error I would turn it off because I don't think it's particularly useful to me. ESLint is only as opionated as you make it.

Comment: The documentation for the rule has a code example http://jsfiddle.net/baconpat/yZPj8/ which would be tricky to debug.  It does seem like kind of an edge case. But in this case I think the code could benefit from some restructuring (that would remove the lint error) anyway.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but instead of assigning into the parameter can't you make it functional and clone `userService` and return the modified clone? Is it an expensive object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest restructuring the code, because now it relies on mutations inside of a `.map` call, which could become pretty hard to reason about. I cant check that my suggested code actually works, but I think it expresses the intent of what you are trying to do more clearly.

**Edit**. Explanation: In short, we have a list of users where only some are relevant. That tells us we probably would want the code to start with `users.filter`. The general idea is to filter out users that have admin rights for the selected service. So I tried to extract that logic into one function (`userHasAdminRightsForService`), which I implemented as a function that returns the function that we will want to use to filter the users. Because of this design, we get code that reads more like regular English: `users.filter(userHasAdminRightsForService(selectedService))` instead of `users.filter(user => userHasAdminRightsForService(user, selectedService))`.

[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is used to check if an array has at least one element that meets some criteria. So a line like `userService.rights.some(right => lowCase(right.name) === 'admin')` means that we check if at least one of the rights in `userService.rights` satisfy the criteria that it should have the name 'admin'.

```js
// given a serviceToCheckFor, return a function that checks if 
// one specific user has any userService, with admin rights, that match the name of serviceToCheckFor
export const userHasAdminRightsForService = serviceToCheckFor = user => {
  return user.services.some(userService => 
    // name check
    userService.name === serviceToCheckFor.name &&
    // check if there exists a non-disabled admin right 
    userService.rights
      .filter(right => !right.disabled)
      .some(right => lowCase(right.name) === 'admin')
    );
}; 

export const renderServiceAdmins = (users, selectedService) => {
    const adminsForSelectedService = users
      .filter(user => !user.disabled)
      .filter(userHasAdminRightsForService(selectedService))

  return adminsForSelectedService.map( admin => 
     (<li key={admin.email + randId()}>
        { admin.name } | <span className="info_blue">{ admin.email }</span>
     </li>)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid, but [as the rule points out](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign), modifying or reassignment of function parameters can lead to unintended behavior.

Generally if you don't want to disable a rule completely in the `.eslintrc` file but only want to suppress specific occurrence of an eslint error use one of [rule-disabling comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments), it also somewhat indicates you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could rewrite without disabling the rule?

```
export const renderServiceAdmins = (users, selectedService) => {
  var admins =  users.reduce((serviceAdmins, user) => {
                    user.services
                        .forEach((service) =>{
                            if(service.name === selectedService.name) {
                                service.rights
                                    .forEach((right)=> {
                                        if( lowCase(right.name) === 'admin' && !right.disabled) {
                                            serviceAdmins.concat[{
                                                name: user.name,
                                                name: user.email
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                        });
                    return serviceAdmins;
                }, []);
    return admins.map(admin=> {
        return (
            <li key={admin.email + randId()}>
              { admin.name } | <span className="info_blue">{ admin.email }</span>
            </li>
          );
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to simplify the code with a functional style, this seems a lot harder to follow

Comment: Ah sorry about that. There was no mention about wanting to rewrite to a functional style . That explains the rule i guess. Then the other answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up solving it this way, much cleaner and way less code too (removed 2 functions)!
Missing part was chaining filters then using `.find`

```
export const renderServiceAdmins = (users, theService) =>
  users
    .filter(user => !user.disabled)
    .filter(user => user.services.find(
      usrSrv => (
        usrSrv.name === theService.name &&
        usrSrv.rights.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() === 'admin' && !r.disabled)
      )
    ))
    .map(user => (
      <li key={user.email + randId()}>
        { user.name } | <span className="info_blue">{ user.email }</span>
      </li>
    ));
```

Comment: Nice that you found something that worked! Now, not to be that guy.. but this seems to be pretty much the exact same code I suggested, but with the filter lambda in-lined instead of extracted as a named function.  (And using `.find` instead of `.some`.) Would it be fair to say that the information in my answer solved your issue? Or is the similarity a mere coincidence? (Not saying that couldn't happen).